# Look Out At, Look Out To

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the difference in meaning between "***look outside at***" and "***look outside to***".  Suppose Mike is sitting in the inside of a cafe.  The cafe has a glass store front so people inside could outside.  Also, the cafe store front faces a parking lot.  Suppose the Mike seated in the cafe:

> 1. Mike ***looked out*** ***at*** the parking lot.
> 2. Mike ***looked out to*** the parking lot.

Sentences similar to 1 & 2 could be found on the web.  How are "looked out **at**" and "looked out **to**" interpret differently?

Answer (score 3):

"To look at [some thing]" means to specifically *pay attention* to that thing.

"To look to [some thing]" has various meanings, but in this context it means to look *in the direction of* that thing.

So if I say I'm looking *at* the parking lot, I mean that the parking lot itself is my focus.  However if I just look *to* the parking lot, I'm just looking over toward that area with no special focus.

Similarly:

> She's looking *at* the sky  (There's something in the sky that has attracted her interest)
>
> She's looking *to* the sky  (She's looking generally upwards with no particular focus)

As a side note, to look *to* a person [has a different meaning](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/look-to), "to hope or expect to get help, advice, etc. from someone":

> I look to you to take care of the kids while I'm away.
>
> Mary looks to Tom to cook their meals since she's been sick.

**Edit:**  In a recent comment I wrote:

> ".. traders who deal in Netflix stock primarily **look to** subscriber statistics to determine whether they will buy or sell."

I used *to* rather than *at*, partly because I was still thinking about this question, but also to imply that the statistics aren't the *only* thing the traders look at -- they look at the statistics *and other related data*.